# Triggers in MySQL

Tags: mysql, triggers

I have database of Real Estate. In that I want to delete a record after particular time event say 22 days. I want to write trigger that will delete record from table automatically after 22 days.

Comment: You don't want to use a Trigger for that, but rather a scheduled EVENT...

Comment: @sgeddes  I already wrote event in mysql as said by you. I given time interval as 1 minute for testing. Bust still it not affecting table data. CREATE EVENT delete_expired_record 
ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 MINUTE DO
DELETE FROM tb_user WHERE bdate < NOW();

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this:

```
CREATE EVENT CheckDeletes
ON SCHEDULE 
EVERY 1 DAY 
DO 
  DELETE FROM YourTable WHERE DATEDIFF(NOW(), YourField) > 22
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-event.html

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Triggers fire immediately based on some particular action in the database.  What you will probably need to to do is to create a script that you can run at scheduled intervals (via cron or similar) in order to look for records older than 22 days or whatever and delete them.